# Question based on solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q: Find the solution of the differential equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\cos x(3\cos y-7\sin x-3)}{\sin y(3\sin x-7\cos y+7)}=0 $$

---

My attempt: I rearranged the equation and ended up with:

\begin{eqnarray}
3(\sin x\sin y\,dy+\cos x\cos y\,dx)+7\sin y dy&=&7(\sin x\cos x\,dx+\sin y\cos y\,dy)\\&+&3\cos x\,dx 
\end{eqnarray}
Unable to proceed further.

Comment: Move all terms to the same members and look for total differentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes of variables reduces the ODE to a separable ODE (below).

The solution, expressed on the form of an implicit equation is :
$$\left(\sin(x)-\cos(y)+1\right)^2\left(\sin(x)+\cos(y)-1\right)^5=c$$

[image]